# All possible combinations of a word

Tags: c, string, recursion, permutation

I was in a job interview and they asked me to generate a list of all possible **permutations** of a given **string**. My solution was inefficient and the guy that interview me told me that i was supposed to use recursion.
Does anyone know this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic interview question, the solution goes something like that:

```
int permu(char* str, size_t len ,size_t index )
{   
    size_t i = index - 1;

    if(index == len) { printf ("%s\n",str); } 

    while (++i < len)
    { 
        swap (str,index,i);           /* swap between index and i */
        permu(str, len ,index + 1 );  /* recorsion */
        swap (str,index,i);           /* swap back between index and i */
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Note, that in this code the user should give 0 in the index parmether
so its better to call this function like this:

```
int permutations(char* str, size_t len)
{
    return (permu(str, len ,0));
}

static int permu(char* str, size_t len ,size_t index )
{ //....}
```